# SDL_surface that contains several images

Tags: c++, sdl

Suppose I have a `SDL_Surface` that is just one image.
What if I wanted to make that `SDL_Surface` have three copies of that image, one below the other?

I came up with this function, but it doesn't show anything:

```
void ElementView::adjust() 
{
    int imageHeight = this->img->h;
    int desiredHeight = 3*imageHeight;

    int repetitions =  desiredHeight / imageHeight ;
    int remainder = desiredHeight % imageHeight ;

    SDL_Surface* newSurf = SDL_CreateRGBSurface(img->flags, img->w, desiredHeight, 32, img->format->Rmask, img->format->Gmask, img->format->Bmask,img->format->Amask);

    SDL_Rect rect;
    memset(&rect, 0, sizeof(SDL_Rect));
    rect.w = this->img->w;
    rect.h = this->img->h;

    for (int i = 0 ; i < repetitions ; i++) 
    {
        rect.y = i*imageHeight;
        SDL_BlitSurface(img,NULL,newSurf,&rect);
    }
    rect.y += remainder;
    SDL_BlitSurface(this->img,NULL,newSurf,&rect);

    if (newSurf != NULL) {
        SDL_FreeSurface(this->img);
        this->img = newSurf;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there any reason you can't just blit the original image several times instead?

Comment: @Xymostech, i'm not supposed to touch the code that actually draws the surface onto the screen.

Comment: I think the problem is that `img` isn't large enough to hold 3 copies of itself in it. It doesn't look like there's a good way to create new surfaces with arbitrary size. Why can't you touch the code that does the actual drawing?

Comment: I tried creating a new surface with `SDL_CreateRGBSurface` that is just as `img` but with the desired height, and then blitting onto that, but it shows an empty image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should

- Create a new surface that is 3 times as long as the initial one
- Copy from `img` to the new surface using code similar to what you have (SDL_BlitSurface), except having the destination as your new surface
- SDL_FreeSurface on your original `img`
- Assign your new surface to `img`

**Edit:** Here is some sample code, didn't have time to test it though...

```
void adjust(SDL_Surface** img)
{
    SDL_PixelFormat *fmt = (*img)->format;
    SDL_Surface* newSurf = SDL_CreateRGBSurface((*img)->flags, (*img)->w, (*img)->h * 3, fmt->BytesPerPixel * 8, fmt->Rmask, fmt->Gmask, fmt->Bmask, fmt->Amask);

    SDL_Rect rect;
    memset(&rect, 0, sizeof(SDL_Rect));
    rect.w = (*img)->w;
    rect.h = (*img)->h;

    int i = 0;
    for (i ; i < 3; i++) 
    {
        SDL_BlitSurface(*img,NULL,newSurf,&rect);
        rect.y += (*img)->h;
    }

    SDL_FreeSurface(*img);
    *img = newSurf;
}
```

Comment: @l19 Are you sure you actually changed the real image, and not just your pointer to it? You probably freed the correct image and then forgot to save the new one. Hint: you will need a double pointer to do this correctly.

Comment: `SDL_Surface* surface = SDL_CreateRGBSurface(....);    SDL_BlitSurface(img,NULL,surface,&rect);

if (surface != NULL) {
  SDL_FreeSurface(img);

  img = surface;

 }`

Comment: @l19 like Xymostech said, pass either a pointer to your SDL_Surface* img, so SDL_Surface** img or a reference, you need to change where it points to!

Comment: @l19 no no no! follow the steps i gave you, you can't Free until you COPIED the data, use SDL_BlitSurface

Comment: @emartel, check my previous comment

Comment: @l19 You're not copying the data.